# SQL Error 213, Column Name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server

I'm getting this error when trying to run this SQL Command:

```
DECLARE @data INT = 1;
WHILE @data = 1
BEGIN 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[WeeklyReport])
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[WeeklyReportLogs]
SELECT *, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DayofData
FROM [dbo].[WeeklyReport]
SET @data = 0
END
ELSE
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'
END
```

Both tables have the same named columns and same value types. This command works for 2 other tables that are set up the same way also. What should I look for that may be different? I've dropped both tables and started from scratch a number of times and still results in this error.

I just need the data from the weeklyreport(records daily) input the data into WeeklyReportLogs(this will house previous day's data recorded into WeeklyReport).

WeeklyReport Definition:

```
Agent Name  varchar no  50                  yes no  yes SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
TotalBreak  int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
TotalLunch  int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
TotalLogin  int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
DayofData   varchar no  50                  yes no  yes SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

WeeklyReportLogs Definition:

```
Agent Name  varchar no  50                  yes no  yes SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
TotalBreak  int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
TotalLunch  int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
TotalLogin  int no  4   10      0       yes (n/a)   (n/a)   NULL
```

Comment: post both of your tables definition so we can try to understand the problem

Comment: I did remove it also so it'll match the DATEADD column and still same error

Comment: DayofData, the one you referenced.

Comment: @Lamak, just added both definitions

Comment: It doesn't seem like `WeeklyReportLogs` has a `DayofData` column, and even if it had one, you'll still get the problem that @JamesZ said

Comment: Don't store dates as varchar, that will cause problems later

Comment: Just deleted DayofData column from weeklyreport also and still same error, same error also when adding the column to the weeklyreportlogs (vice versa)

Comment: why are you adding and removing columns at random?, the issue is simple, you need to insert the same number of columns that your `SELECT` is providing

Comment: I understand this maybe simple in which case I'm still getting this error when inserting the same number of columns or so I think. I delete the column to match the number of columns, I have also added them back, still same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, try to avoid using `*` in your queries. Its behavior may lead to trouble as it is statically expanded into the actual column when the object (view, stored procedure etc.) is compiled, not when run.

If both `[dbo].[WeeklyReportLogs]` and `dbo.WeeklyReport` have the same number of columns (n) then:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[WeeklyReportLogs]                -- n columns
SELECT *, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DayofData  -- n+1 columns
FROM [dbo].[WeeklyReport]
```

Also, try to always specify columns in inserts, as schema changes may lead to failures when object is run (not when table is changed):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[WeeklyReportLogs]  
(column1, column2,  .... etc)              
SELECT {actual columns here}, DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS DayofData  
FROM [dbo].[WeeklyReport]
```

Comment: this appeared to do the trick but I'm puzzled because I have the same setup as listed in my question for another SQL command and it works fine. the definitions are exactly the same as the ones I posted in the question also.